# validating username and password in xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have List which has username and password in it. i have a login with two entry elements and a button. If username and password combination in the entry elements are not in the List, it should return false but if it does exist, it should navigate to the next page. Xamarin forms c#

Comment: Are you   collecting bids on this project, or what?

Comment: No im not. I just need help

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: how is "List which has username and password" defined?  Show us the actual code that defines this object.

Comment: I dont know how to go about the validation on button click. If i input a username and password in the entry elements and i click, i want it to go to the page i set it to if the username and password exsits. If not, i should return false.

Comment: @jason. this is my List definition;

namespace TestPage
{
 class LoginService
    {
      public  List<UserLogin> Login = new List<UserLogin> { 
         new UserLogin {UserName="Faith", Password="12345"},
         new UserLogin {UserName="Classyk", Password="1234"},
         new UserLogin {UserName="Eruku", Password="123"}
      };
        public UserLogin Validate(string username,string password)
        {
            return Login.Where(c => c.UserName==username && c.Password==password);
        }
    }
}.

Comment: Please store never a password in clear text!

Comment: Hey tobias, yes i know. It was all just for test

Comment: Hey tobias, yes i know. It was all just for test

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

// assumes username and password contain the relevant user input

// uses Linq's Any clause to test if Any entry in the list matches
if (Login.Any(l => l.UserName == username && l.Password == password))
{
  // login matched, go to next page
}
else 
{
  // login did not match
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot jason. It worked !! I guess i need to learn linq queries